# Kinect Heart Beat open source project

Tags: kinect

The Kinect 2 for Windows is capable of detecting heart rates, but it's not implemented in the SDK. I've found one sample (https://k4wv2heartrate.codeplex.com/), but he has not released the source code for his work.

Have anyone used any open source library for detecting heart beat for Kinect 2 for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since nobody has answered in 4 days, let me share what I know and see if it helps.

I haven't worked with Kinect 2 yet, nor have looked at its SDK capabilities. But I know that the trick to heartbeat detection lies in the user's image when viewed through a camera with infrared capabilities. When there is a heartbeat, the skin color changes. Try to see if you can make the RGB camera enter that mode, and then simply detect the color changes in the user's skin.